# use react-chat-elements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, messagebox, adonis.js

I am a newbie React programmer. For now, I am using [React ChatBox Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chatbox-component) as the front end library and [AdonisJS websocket](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/websocket) as the backend library to achieve a chat system. However, the React-ChatBox-Component doesn't support send files and photos. So I am looking for some other libraries, such as [react-chat-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-elements). But as far as I know, it is actually built for react-native, not reactJS. I am wondering if I can just use this library in my reactJS project, or is there any other good library for building a chat system with files/photos compatible?

Comment: I recommend you installing it and trying it yourself. If you come up any problems you can't figure out, come and ask again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react
Dedicaded media messages are not available yet, but its fully customizable, so you can simply add your own.
Also you need some server logic for handlig media messages.